How do I connect Nginx-proxy-manager to a site running on a docker, both on the same personal server?
Got a 404 page not found with Nginx-proxy-manager
Hi, I'm trying to deploy a pypi server to upload my personal package to my personal server using DNS with nginx and my domain name from Cloudflare.
To do this, I'm using Nginx-proxy-manager in a docker-compose with ports 81, 80, 443. My pypi server is also used in a docker-compose with port 8080.
I've also opened my port in my network and configured my DNS in Cloudflare to redirect the url to my public IP.
In my Nginx-proxy-manager, I put my private IP server and the port of my pypi server in a proxy host. I also create an SSL certificate from Cloudflare and place it as a custom SSL certificate in Nginx.
docker-compose.yaml for Nginx-Proxy-Manager :
version: '3.8'
name: nginx-proxy-manager
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

docker-compose.yaml for pypi-server :
version: '3.7'

services:
  pypi-server:
    image: pypiserver/pypiserver:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ec2-user/pypi/auth
        target: /data/auth
      - type: volume
        source: pypi-server
        target: /data/packages
    command: -P /data/auth/.htpasswd -a update,download,list /data/packages
    restart: always

volumes:
  pypi-server:

When I try to access my pypi server with the url, I get an error: "404 page not found".
But when I try to access the pypi server with my private ip server, I can get the page and access it.
I've tried many things, changing the SSL generation, trying with another website with ArgoCD, but I get the same "404 page not found" error. When I check the log files of my pypi container or the Nginx logs, I get no errors.
